# SPSS: How to count number of digits in variable

Tags: spss

**I need to count the number of digits in an SPSS numeric variable, and assign it to a different variable.**

I tried converting it to a string and counting the length of the string with `char.length()`, but this returns the defined length of the variable, rather than the length of the actual string in each line.

**Any ideas how this can be done?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when canculating the length of your string variable, use `ltrim`or `rtrim`(depending on how you calculated your string - just to be sure you could use both) to get rid of spaces and count only digits:

```
compute Ndigits=char.length(ltrim(rtrim(YourString))).
```

you could also do away with the text variable altogether and just use this function:

```
compute Ndigits=trunc(lg10(YourNumber))+1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the length will depend on how the number was converted to a string, i.e., the number of decimals specified in the conversion.  Also, the decimal point character will contribute to the length.

Also, if you are in Unicode mode, which has been the default for several years, you don't need to use char.rtrim.  Strings are automatically rtrimmed in that mode.

Comment: Yes, I thought about the added decimals and changed formats before altering type, and I am indeed in Unicode mode, but I still get the whole variable width with 'char.length()'.

Comment: According to the doc, "CHAR.LENGTH("strexpr) returns the length of strexpr in characters with any trailing blanks removed".  This is the behavior I see in a simple test.  I don't know why you are seeing different behavior, but maybe you have nonprinting but nonblank trailing characters.  You could change the format to AHEX to see if that is the case.